# Serving (Angular) WebComponents individually over NestJS backend

Tags: angular, nestjs, server-side-rendering, web-component, native-web-component

I'm looking for a solution to do the following:

I have a NestJS backend running on a server that has a route named `/api/getWebComponent`

I want it to return plain HTML so that it can be rendered into our online-shop.

Ideally I don't wanna write plain HTML, but use Angular to create a web-native Web-Component using @angular/elements.

I struggle to understand how I would do that. I know I can serve static files with NestJS. Is this what I wanna do here? Simply statically serve the index.html of the Web-Component? And whoever calls the endpoint then receives that index.html and renders it inside its application?

The same NestJS Backend already serves an Angular frontend on root level `/` but that shouldn't be important for this question.

Can this be done? I feel like I'm not asking the right question here/ dont know how to ask the right question here because I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. If you want the Angular application to be able to communicate with the NestJS application, you can do so as follows.

1. `index.html` of Angular application serves by static web server like apache, nginx, (or just NextJS) on 80 port.
2. All dynamic request from Angular application should have prefix, usually it is `/api`.
3. Run NestJS application on 3000 port (or other) and write all endpoint with prefix `/api`.
4. In static web servers write rule to redirect all request with prefix `/api` to 3000 port for NestJS application.

But maybe you don't know how to publish dynamic content as HMTL? Your API endpoint (NestJS) should returns text with header `content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`